# Reading JSON RDD using Spark Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am receiving JSON data from Kafka brokers and I am reading it using Spark Streaming and Scala. Following is the example data:

```
{"timestamp":"2020-12-11 22:35:00.000000 UTC","tech":"Spark","version":2,"start_time":1607725688402210,"end_time":1607726131636059}
```

I receive this data as RDD[String] in my Scala code , now I want to read particular key from each data row, for example 'version' from the above data.
I am able to do this as follows:

```
for(record <- rdd){
  val jsonRecord = JSON.parseFull(record );
  val globalMap = jsonRecord.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
  val version = globalMap.get("version").get.asInstanceOf[String]
}
```

But I am not sure if this is the best way to read RDD having JSON data. Please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: can you use spark structured streaming? or don't want to?

Comment: I am using direct stream to fetch the Raw stream and then looping over that.

Comment: Spark version is 2.3.0.2

Comment: why are using dstream, it going to be deprecated ?

Comment: I have an existing running code in production and can not make much changes to it. For now I need to achieve some use case with existing code base. Thanks,

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: I need to fetch some particular keys from the messages and perform some calculation on that . Final calculation to go in to flat file.

Comment: looks to me as if you are using scala.util.parsing.json.JSON, do you have other Json libraries you can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json4s` library to parse json data & It will be available with spark default no need to import extra libraries.

Check below code.

```
scala> rdd.collect.foreach(println)

{"timestamp":"2020-12-11 22:35:00.000000 UTC","tech":"Spark","version":2,"start_time":1607725688402210,"end_time":1607726131636059}
```

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

rdd.map{ row =>

    // Import required libraries for json parsers.
    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

    // parse json message using parse function from json4s lib.

    val jsonData = parse(row)

    // extract required fields from parsed json data.

    // extracting version field value
    val version = (jsonData \\ "version").extract[Int] 

    // extracting timestamp field value
    val timestamp = (jsonData \\ "timestamp").extract[String] 

    (version,timestamp)
}
.collect
.foreach(println)


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

(2,2020-12-11 22:35:00.000000 UTC)
```

Comment: Thanks Srinivas. It fits well for my use case.